# populate a People/Group field which allow multiple selection using PnP Power shell for SharePoint Online

Tags: powershell

I have a SharePoint online field named "HRContacts" which allow multiple selection:-

[image]

and using PnP Power Shell i want to create a new list item and populate this field among with other fields. i have this Power Shell script, but i got the below error:-

```
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> $HRCollabs = [System.Collections.ArrayList]@()
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> $testuser  = Get-PnPAzureADUser -Filter  { Mail eq 'test@******.com'}
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> $HRCollabs.Add($testuser)
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> Add-PnPListItem -List "customlist" -Values @{HRContacts= $HRCollabs; Title = '123'}
Add-PnPListItem : The specified user  could not be found.
At line:1 char:1
+ Add-PnPListItem -List "customlist" -Values @{HRContacts= $HRCollabs; Titl ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [Add-PnPListItem], PSInvalidOperationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvalidOperation,PnP.PowerShell.Commands.Lists.AddListItem
```

Any advice?
Thanks

Comment: Cannot test myself, but try `@{HRContacts= $HRCollabs.UserPrincipalName}`

Comment: @Theo yes it worked ... i though since $HRCollabs is an array i can not directly reference the UPN..